# mocking in go. Is there an easy way?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, mocking

I come from python and I have been looking for a way to write yests in go. I have come across a few things on SO but they all seem very cumbersome and verbose for something that shpuld be needed all the time.

I am typing on mobile now, will add code later if needed...but for example...

say i have a function that calls `smtp.Send` somewhere in the middle. how can I easily test this function?

Say i have another one that hits some outside api (needs mocking) and then takes the response and calls something like `ioutil.Readall()`...how could i make my way through this test function and mock the call to the api and then pass some fake response data when `Readall` is called?

Comment: Post some cod otherwise it's quite difficult know what you are trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using an interface. For example let's say you have an interface called Mailer:

```
type Mailer interface {
    Send() error
}
```

Now you can embed a Mailer object into the function that calls the `Send` method.

```
type Processor struct {
    Mailer
}

func (p *Processor) Process() {
    _ = p.Mailer.Send()
}
```

Now in your test you can create a mock Mailer.

```
type mockMailer struct{}
//implement the Send on the mockMailer as you wish

p := &Processor{
    Mailer: mockMailer,
}

p.Process()
```

when `p.Process` reaches the `Send` method it calls your mocked `Send` method.

Comment: thanks for the simple example...in this case the function I want to test MUST take the Mailer interface as input....correct?

Comment: @deltaskelta Also, to mock the API call you can use net/http/httptest

Comment: what if we call direclty Mailer.send(), how can we mock it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you are asking. If you already have a an object that implements the Mailer it must be because you have a send function for it. In which case you can just unit test the specific send function. This pattern is typically useful when you are testing the functionality of an object but as part of that you want to use a mock for another internal object.